# The blog is down

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

Trying to visit any link to the blog (which used to work and are still found in Google) says "Domain not found" or similar:

- stackoverflow.blog
- https://stackoverflow.blog
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

It is [down right now](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/stackoverflow.blog.html).

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdw5U.png) - looks like it has a new design now

Comment: Vast improvement IMO, at least on mobile.

Comment: @smitop It does work when I switch to mobile data, but since Isitdownrightnow.com is detecting an outage, I think it might be more than just me having the issue. All other sites (including the rest of SE) are still working no matter which connection I'm on.

Comment: @Laurel I'm on computer with wifi and it works; are you on your phone?

Comment: @bobeyt6 It was my computer that had the problem. Since posting my last comment it started loading again. Maybe it was just down for several minutes as they were switching over to the new system.

Comment: Could be a DNS TTL thing if they've switched to a different IP while overhauling the site. Doesn't work for me just yet.

Comment: No-repro. Looks fine on this end.

Comment: For the record, "isitdownrightnow.com" has given me wrong results today and in the past for other domains. For example, it currently thinks archive.org has been down for the past 55 minutes. It is not.

Comment: I've generally found [downforeveryoneorjustme](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) more reliable.

Comment: Is it just me or is the page load speed of the blog pretty bad. It takes at least 3 seconds for me. I don't know how it was before the overhaul.

Comment: Most likely the outage was caused by changing the blog engine from one cloud to another. It takes a bit of time for the DNS to update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blog is back up - looks like they did a redesign as of 30th August 2023
 <sub>ps: the dark mode switch is at the bottom</sub>