# Mysterious comment content beneath the question title in the "From the Network" feature in Stack Overflow blog

Tags: support, blog

In the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/), there is a new feature named "From the Network" has been introduced at the top of the page. This feature spotlights intriguing questions from various sites within the network.

Beneath each question's title, certain content is presented. Initially, I presumed this to be a partial excerpt from the question's description, but it turns out not to be the case.

For instance, consider a question from [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/63675):

**Question title:**

> Apollo: what was the big deal?

**Extra content:**

> Pfft, first man in space. My kid could do that.

This appears to be a humorous comment related to the post. Is this additional content manually added by someone, or is it an AI-generated comment for the post?

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Question content]

Comment: Are they accusing Racoons of being thieves? That's speciesist

Comment: Looks like it's the continuation of the "Interesting questions" from "The Overflow" newsletters (e.g. [#191](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/08/18/the-overflow-191-between-product-and-engineering/), [#192](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/08/25/the-overflow-192-ask-your-data-better-questions/)) :)

Answer (score 8):

In [my own question about the blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392647/any-details-about-the-blog-redesign), I have asked the developer in a comment to the answer:

> What determines the “From our Network”? Is it manually selected by someone, or automatically collected using some formula?

The reply was:

> These are handpicked by our Content Team

So I'm pretty sure the content team employee who handpick the posts also add the funny comment, no AI involved.

Comment: One would guess even an AI would know the Vostok program had the first man in space, not the Appolo program...

Comment: (Not necessarily. LLMs don't really "know" things. On the other hand, an LLM would not misspell Apollo.)

Comment: @tripleee Funny how LLMs seem not to hallucinate spelling, especially given the ostensibly sorry state of the training data, yet seem to hallucinate everything else...